# Is it possible to adjust the login policy when using the SandboxPostCopy interface?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

We have single-sign on enabled and for our production org it is very useful to have the My Domain settings set to prevent login from login.salesforce.com.  However every time we create/refresh a sandbox we need to disable this which is very annoying.  I've been researching into using the SandboxPostCopy Interface to automatically create some test data within my sandboxes when they are created/refreshed, is it possible to disable the login policy as part of this?
[image]